# UIWebView Screen Fitting Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, uiwebview

I have developed a website in `Twitter Bootstrap`, I am now using a `UIWebView` to display that site inside of an IOS app. I am getting it to display fine, but the screen is off and it is running off of the side of the screen... I feel like I might have my UIWebView configured wrong, the site looks like if I go to it in Safari on my mobile device, so I know the site is working properly.

It even displays Google wrong in the UIWebView.... I will display my code and 2 screen shots below(The first screenshot is what it currently looks like, the second is what it should look like and what it looks like in safari mobile :

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_webView loadRequest:request];
_webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
_webView.frame=self.view.bounds;

[_webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**AS-IS Screen Shot**

[image: AS-IS Screenshot]

**TO-BE Screen Shot**

[image: To-Be Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the UIWebView is not set up correctly in the Storyboard or Interface Builder. Do you use [Auto Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zma4D.png)? If so, are the constraints set correctly?

A simple way to make sure the UIWebView is displayed full screen would be to add 4 constraints that align it with the top, bottom, leading and trailing edges of its superview, e.g. like so:

[image]

EDIT: [Here are some rough instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hr2r.jpg) on how to add those constraints.

Comment: Im not able to find where I can add constraints? I see this "the selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view."

Comment: And yes, I am using Auto Layout

Comment: @codeBoy added a screenshot with some hints to the answer

Comment: So it looks like if I select the command that said "Add missing constraints" it fixed the issue... So weird that me manually adding them didn't do the job. Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `loadRequest:` two time, Use:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [_webView reload];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following code after `[_webView loadRequest:request];` :

```
_webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

and If your UIWebView is not located properly, add the following code too :

```
_webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
```

Comment: I added the above to my code and it did not work... Same result.... I will update my code in question with what I have

Answer (score 0):

In the Utilities pane, select "Scales Pages to Fit":

[image: desc]

In the view controller in which the web view resides, make sure you can view the boxes (or bounds) of the view (note: the bottom doesn't appear because I couldn't fit it within the image):

[image: desc2]

Code in view controller:

```
#import "SomeViewController.h"

@interface SomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation SomeViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *urlLink = @"www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlLink];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Photo of the other settings in the view controller:

[image: desc3]

Comment: Have you drawn the webview so that it fills the entire screen as well? And made sure the width does not extend beyond the screen? (I'll add photo)

Comment: Yeah... I have it set up like that too

Comment: I've added my code. See if using that works for you.

Comment: Ok, giving it a try now. Standby

Comment: Adding a photo, let me know if you have same settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80002/discussion-between-codeboy-and-will-campbell).